# Categories with products in a view

Tags: views

I like to create a table where the first column is the category (what is in a dictionary) and the next 4 columns are some products from this category. Here is an example: http://www.numark.com/categories

How can I create it it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "Implementing a functionality or a layout seen in a site, for which just a description of the feature, a screenshot, or a site URL is provided" [is not allowed here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: you can do it by using format view using views by select the format "Table"